# What is causing the repetition of names when web scraping with Selenium and how can I solve it?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

[image: imgage reference]

I am trying to scrap a webpage that has a list of doctors name ,my search result shows me that i have 21 results, but when i try to print the result i getting the same name 21 times. i think there is a problem in the loop but i don't know to correct it please help this is the site link https://www.doctoralia.com.mx/ , thanks

i need to find all name list for the search result ,but iam getting the same name 21 times

Comment: Hey, did my answer solved your problem? or need more help

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code as plain text. I embedded the screenshot, because it provides useful debugging information, but code as plain text is easiest to read and copy to an answer if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "." (dot) at start on Xpath when looking on elements, "/" is root so you will get always first element found

```
your_xpath = ".//span"
```

Comment: upvote are welcome, but mark it as answered to close it

Answer (score 0):

You can collect directly the doctor names and then loop through it

```py
doctors = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span["data-ga-label"="Doctor Name"]')

for doctor in doctors:
  name_list.append(doctor.text)

print(name_list)
```